# Multi IP Addresses for SSL sites on Azure VM machine

Tags: powershell, azure, iis, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

i am trying to add multi ssl sites to my azure vm machine, but i am missing something.
i tried "Add-AzureVirtualIP" ,"New-AzureReservedIP","Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation","Set-AzurePublicIP"

i can see the new ip in powershell , but when i add the bindings in the iis dialog box, its doesn't work
on my own servers i usually added the new IPs that my isp provided withen the network ip4 properties and it was so easy, now i have no internal ips nor external port forword working
any ideas